# How to generate URL from Laravel route in Javascript

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I need to pass a ajax variable as route parameter, but it is showing an error.

This is the error:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PermissaoController::status(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected
```

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#status_id').change(function(){
      var usuario = (location.pathname).split('/');
      var status = this.value;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: "{{route('permissao.status', "+status+")}}",
    data: {status: status, usuario: usuario[2]},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(html){
      $('#projeto_id').find('option').remove();
      $('#projeto_id').append('<option value="">Selecione...</option>');
      for(var i = 0; i< html.length;i++){
        $('#projeto_id').append('<option value="'+html[i]['id']+'">'+html[i]['titulo']+ '-' + html[i]['codigo']+ '</option>');
      }
    }
  })
})
```

})

This is my function in controller:

```
public function status($sd)   {
    $usuario = Usuario::where('id', $sd)->get();
    return $usuario;   
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: can you post your routes

Comment: Anything within the `{{ ... }}` delimiters is processed server-side. You cannot inject your client-side `status` variable into it

Answer (score 2):

**If you want to use route.**

```
var status = this.value;    
var url ="{{route('permissao.status', ":status")}}";
url = url.replace(":status", status);
```

Use variable url with ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

You cant pass JavaScript  to laravel route method.

It should be

```
  url: "permissao/status/"+status,
```

if you face base url issue then you can do the following

```
var url="{{url('/')}}/";
```

then in ajax

```
 url: url+"permissao/status/"+status,
```